# Retrieving ResponseCode,ResponseDescription,Amount and CardNumber

Tags: php, soap

I have been trying to retrieve the ResponseCode,ResponseDescription,Amount and CardNumber using simplexml but it keeps returning an empty string.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
    <GetTransactionDataResponse xmlns="http://services.interswitchng.com/">
    <GetTransactionDataResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebPAY.Core.ServiceFramework.Contract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ResponseCode xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TechQuest.Framework.ServiceFramework.Contract">61</ResponseCode><ResponseDescription xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TechQuest.Framework.ServiceFramework.Contract">Exceeds Withdrawal Limit</ResponseDescription>
    <a:Amount>10000000</a:Amount>
    <a:CardNumber>3386</a:CardNumber>
    <a:LeadBankCbnCode i:nil="true"/><a:LeadBankName i:nil="true"/>
    <a:MerchantReference i:nil="true"/><a:PaymentReference i:nil="true"/>
    <a:RetrievalReferenceNumber i:nil="true"/><a:SplitAccounts/>
    <a:TransactionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:TransactionDate>
    </GetTransactionDataResult>
    </GetTransactionDataResponse>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Consider posting the code your using to parse the xml and things you have tried to so far to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the soap response I would take a look on [Nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/), it is a webservice library for PHP that handles all conversions to and from xml making it very easy to use webservices.

I have used it alot myself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting this if you are using `Interswitch` Payment System. Use a [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) Instead but if you still need to parse this then :

```
$sxe = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('s', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebPAY.Core.ServiceFramework.Contract');
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

$list = array();
$list['code'] = (string) $sxe->children("s", true)->Body->children()->GetTransactionDataResponse->GetTransactionDataResult->ResponseCode;
$list['desciption'] = (string)  $sxe->children("s", true)->Body->children()->GetTransactionDataResponse->GetTransactionDataResult->ResponseDescription;
$list['amount']  = (string)  $sxe->xpath('//a:Amount');
$list['amount'] = (string)  $list['amount'][0];
$list['card']  = $sxe->xpath('//a:CardNumber');
$list['card'] = (string) $list['card'][0];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [code] => 61
    [desciption] => Exceeds Withdrawal Limit
    [amount] => A
    [card] => 3386
)
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cr7Lf4)